# Animation for jquery hide()

Tags: jquery

is there a way to modify the animation on the hide() element in jquery? I want to change the animation of it, or perhaps even combine two or more to make it more appealing?

```
 $(this).hide('fast');
```

Comment: What animation do you want?

Comment: @Johnツ Anything really, I just want to see examples, or even how you can combine two or more.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/hide/ check this link for all effects

Comment: As well as `fadeout()`, you can also check out `slideUp()` - depending on what kind of animation you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fadeOut the element, just use:

```
$(this).fadeOut();
```

If you want to make another animation, use [`animate()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

Example:

```
$(this).animate({"margin-top": "30px", "opacity": 0});
```

Also, you can use animations calling [`hide()` function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

See the [**options**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-options) parameter.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3JVT9/)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/hide/) then you'll be able to see exactly what you can change in the `hide` function's options:

- duration (default: 400)
- easing (default: swing)
- queue (default: true)
- specialEasing
- step
- progress
- complete
- fail
- always

If you want to change the element's appearance (e.g. height, opacity, color) then you're probably better off using `animate()`: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
slideUp('slow');
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

```
fadeOut('slow');
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/